# Is the following statement is True false regarding inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the  following statement is True false

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^5$ be equipped with the usual euclidean inner-product. 
 If $W$ and $Z$ are subspaces of $V$ such that both of them are of dimension
$3,$ then there exists $z \in Z$ such that $z \neq 0$ and $z ⊥ W.$

My attempt : i thinks this statement  is  True take  $W=  (1,-1,1)$  and $Z=(-1,1,-1)$  the  $Z ⊥ W$ that is  $\langle Z. W\rangle=0$

Is  my thinking is correct or not ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: What if W=Z i.e. W and Z are the same subspace ? The conditions of the question don't seem to rule this out.

Comment: The question is not clear. Your $W$ and $Z$ seem vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so their are not subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^5$ nor elements of this vector space.

Comment: exactly! by the way, I tried to incorporate your comments in my answer, i hope that is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is false, it needs further assumptions, also as stated in the comments, be aware that we are talking subspaces here, not vectors! for example (as gandalf61 said) take $Z=W\subset V$ then we have, since $\langle\_,\_ \rangle$ is non degenerate, for all $0 \neq z \in Z$ a $w \in W=Z$ such that $\langle z , w \rangle \neq 0$ in particular (to give a very concrete example) you could pick $w=z$ and then we already know that $$\langle z, w\rangle = \langle z, z\rangle = 0 \iff z=0$$

Also, be aware that only the concrete counterexample with $z=w$ needs an inner product, for the first one it suffices to have bilinear form $\langle \_ ,\_ \rangle$ inducing a non degenerate bilinearform on $Z=W$.

Comment: thanks u @Enkidu